# Beautiful taxonomy filters post counts with pre_get_posts - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I've got a Wordpress site where I'm using the 'Beautiful' custom taxonomy filters with a custom post type, These posts are assigned with meta value based on a 'type.'

By setting a session variable on each of these sub-pages via the meta value, I can filter through only the posts that contain that same meta, Using the code below in `functions.php`:

```
<?php 
function thisCategory( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'knowledge-center' ) ) {
        $cat = $_SESSION['kc-sub'];
        $metaquery = array(
                        array(
                           'key' => 'type', // name of custom field
                           'value' => $cat,
                           'compare' => 'LIKE',

                            ),
                        );
        if ( isset($_SESSION["kc-sub"]) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_query',$metaquery);
        return;
        } else {

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'thisCategory', 1 ); 
?>
```

However, the drop downs for the plug-in are looking throughout the whole CPT - So I'm getting post counts for all posts registered within the selected taxonomy/taxonomies.

I'm trying to have the dropdowns query that taxonomy, within posts that have a meta value of my session, So we can retrieve accurate post counts displayed.

I've been looking at the filter [beautiful_filters_dropdown_categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/beautiful-taxonomy-filters/other_notes/) which can manipulate `wp_dropdown_categories`, but I'm having strange results of having all dropdowns displaying the same values using this method.

Comment: You might attempt to look at what you are doing yourself. The code above will only run on the archive page for the CPT "knowledge-center". From what you are asking above it appears you want to run this within posts - on a single post template?

Comment: Nope, not quite. The plugin seems to only run on the archive page, i.e. whenever you filter any options, it pushes you back to the archive page and displays those options, if that makes sense?

So when i click on my single page for say my type 'Tools' i set a session which is 'Tools', so then when i use the filter on this page, and it pushes me back to the main archive, the query above can run against the meta value and output only posts that match.

It's the dropdown's themselves however which i need to restrict, so they only display counts of posts within the CPT that have the session value.

Comment: that took a while to decode....i think i know what you are on about. The code above is only setting the main query but you can have multiple queries and the main query is obviously not being used for the dropdowns (because it has not changed), so you need to find the code that is getting the values for the dropdowns. If the developer put filters in there for the wp_query it will be easy enough, if not you have to replace with your own method.